# Where were Yaakov's sons buried?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, shevatim-12-tribes, vayechi

The end of parshat Vayechi has Yosef requesting that he be buried in Cana'an. [At the end](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0624.htm#32) of book of Yehoshua, we see that he was buried in Shchem.

Where were the other brothers buried? Beginning of Shemot implies that they died in Egypt, but we're they all buried there, too, or were any remains carried into Cana'an?

Comment: Dupe : https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79083/yaakovs-sons-kvarim/79095?r=SearchResults#79095

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yerushalmi Sota 8b Chapter 1 Halacha 10 says that all the 12 Shevatim were taken to Eretz Yisrael by their Shevet.

> **תלמוד ירושלמי סוטה דף ח' ע"ב, פרק א' הלכה י'** – ככתוב בראשית מו אנכי ארד עמך מצרים ואני אעלך גם עלה מה ת"ל גם עלה. אמר אותך אני מעלה ושאר כל השבטים אני מעלה מלמד שכל שבט ושבט העלה עצמות ראש שבטו עמו

Regarding where in Israel the individual Shevatim are buried is a matter of good old Jewish dispute.

Answer (score 4):

As stated by @Gershon Gold, the locations are disputed. The following is the version from Sefer Seder Ha'dorot:

> ויקברו את ארונות מטות אבותיהם בנחלת בניהם, את ראובן וגד בעבר הירדן ברומא, ושמעון ולוי בעיר מנדא אשר נתנה לבני שמעון ויהי מגרש העיר לבני לוי, ואת יהודה בעיר בנימין נגד בית לחם, ועצמות יששכר וזבולן בצידון בחלק אשר נפל לבניהם, ודן באשתאול, ונפתלי ואשר בקדש נפתלי, ועצמות יוסף קברו בשכם בחלקת השדה אשר קנה יעקב. ובנימין קברו בירושלים. נגד היבוסי אשר נתן לבני בנימין.‏

Translated:

> And they buried the caskets of their fathers in the land of their sons, Reuven and Gad in the Territories East of the Jordan in Rome, and Shimon and Levi in the city Manda that was given to the Sons of Shimon and the surrounding land was given to the Sons of Levi, and Yehuda in the city Binyamin across Beit Lechem, and Dan in Eshtaol, and Naphtali and Asher in Kedesh Naftali, and Yosef's bones they buried in Shechem in the plot that was bought by Yaakov. And Binyamin they buried in Yerushalayim across the Yevosi that was given to the Sons of Binyamin.

Note: Earlier in the book, it's written that Yehuda was buried in the city of Babiya - בביא.